# AppleScript path relative to script location

Tags: macos, path, applescript, finder

I'm trying to launch a Finder window of a folder that's in the same directory as my script. When I run the code below, it launches a blank Finder window set to the path of the script not to the folder.

```
tell application "Finder"
    tell application "Finder" to make new Finder window
    set file_path to (path to me) as text
    set target of Finder window 1 to file_path
end tell
```

How can I get the path to the folder of the script, not the script?

Comment: Didn't you already asked the same ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789060/play-sound-with-applescript-using-afplay-and-relative-file-path

Answer (score 2):

You were close.  You do not need the text version of the file, you only need the file itself, then you can ask Finder for that file's container:

```
tell application "Finder"
    tell application "Finder" to make new Finder window
    set file_path to (path to me)
    set target of Finder window 1 to file_path's container
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way I know to do this is:

```
tell application "Finder" to open ((path to me as text) & "::")
```

Editing your script renders the following:

```
tell application "Finder"
    make new Finder window -- There is no need for an your second tell statement
    set file_path to (path to me as text) & "::" -- Goes up one directory
    set target of Finder window 1 to file_path
end tell
```