# Installing R with a mac app : why cannot the app find the location of the script?

Tags: ios, r, macos

I made a simple mac os app to install R and a package, using the applescript editor:

```
tell application "Terminal" 
    do script "
pathTo=`pwd`;
sudo installer -pkg R-3.3.1.pkg -target /
R CMD INSTALL $pathTo/R-packages/XML_3.98-1.4.tgz; 
end tell
```

but the script cannot find the directory R-packages, even though R-packages lies in the very same directory as the script. The script always "starts" at the root.

It is possible to get the path using

```
(path to me)
```

See that exchange:
[AppleScript path relative to script location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988539/applescript-path-relative-to-script-location)

but I have'nt managed to insert that alias in the shell script.

This BTW my first mac app, hence I beg your understanding if it looks fuzzy.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
You extract the path using applescript language:

```
set app_path to (path to me)
```

applescript uses ":" instead of "/" between the directories (aka POSIX), you need to convert that path

```
set posix_path to POSIX path of app_path
```

and now use the concatenation tool "&" in applescript to use the path in a shell script:

```
tell application "Terminal"
do script "
R CMD INSTALL " & posix_path & "easyKin-packages/R-packages/XML_3.98-1.4.tgz;"
end tell
```